# How to add a composite to another composite?

Tags: java, swt, composite

Is there a way to add an already constructed composite to an already constructed composite?

```
Composite container = new Composite( shell, style );
Composite contained = OtherCompositeClass.constructAndThenGetComposite();
```

...so, can I add contained to container?

Answer (score 2):

You can call `setParent` to change the parent:

```
contained.setParent(container);
```

However the JavaDoc says:

> Changes the parent of the widget to be the one provided if the
>   underlying operating system supports this feature. Returns true if the
>   parent is successfully changed.

So it might not work. Generally you should avoid messing with the parents of controls.

Note: Controls can only have one parent so the contained Composite will be removed from its previous owner.

Comment: Also see Control.isReparentable(). Javadoc: "Returns true if the underlying operating system supports this reparenting, otherwise false"